# javascript google maps api combined with angular 2 google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3

Specifically is it at all possible to use both javascript([developers.google.com documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)) 
and angular 2 google map ([SebastianM : angular2-google-maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps)) in tandem.

Reason being angular 2 google maps at a very early stage and events are not totally there e.g.map marker right click.

Would also like to know if this affect other possible fields that draw from my angular 2 marker array, will i still be to do data binding.

Comment: I solved this kind of issue by forking angular2-google-maps and implementing my own directives for some features that were not available.

Comment: I'm a newb at angular 2 and deadlines wont allow for me to slowly implement my own directives. thanks for sharing your insight on my problem.

Comment: Well using both google maps AND angular-2-google-maps sounds a bit painful as you will need to duplicate code and if you want to be able to use data binding (note that you don't specify what or how), you will need to implement components or directives.

Comment: Yea I understand that code will be duplicated in both typescript and javascript, mainly want to use data binding to display and possibly edit information on my markers and map itself e.g.change label of marker.